# In a Sveltekit project, how to call a function after a child component has finished

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have to call a function from two components that is located in the layout component that is common for both, but, one function goes after another has finished, and I don't know how to make my component wait until my child component has a response.

```
---root Layout component
-- +Layout.svelte
<script>
import { setContext } from 'svelte';

const IamAuth = () {
  // this logic takes 5 seconds, and have to be call after the GetIsLoggedIn
  
}

const GetIsLoggedIn = () {
  //this take 1 second, but if its call before the IamAuth, throw an error
}

setContext('authContext', {
    IamAuth,
    GetIsLoggedIn,
});
<script>

--NavBar Component
--NavBar.svelte
<script>
import { onMount, getContext } from 'svelte';

const { IamAuth } = getContext('authContext');


onMount(() => {
  IamAuth() //this works ok
});

<script>


--other Layout Component
-- +Layout.svelte
<script>
import { onMount, getContext } from 'svelte';
import NavBar from '$lib/components/NavBar.svelte';

const { GetIsLoggedIn } = getContext('authContext');

onMount(() => {
  GetIsLoggedIn() //this doesn't, because the NavBar Component hasn't finished
                 //how to wait until IamAuth function has ending

<script>

<NavBar />
<slot />
```

I did a diagram to explain my idea, hope it help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

well, at the end, I use this in my child component:

```
{#await loading}
    <h1>loading...</h1>
{:then}
    <NavBar bind:autenticado />
    <slot />
{/await}
```

to prevent that race condition, hope help anybody else

Answer (score 0):

I would try to work with events.

Either using an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) instance within the context to communicate via that, or [dispatching events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to the `window` which then could be listened for via `<svelte:window on:my-event={...}>`.